# Am I using preg_replace correctly (PHP)?

Tags: php, preg-replace

I think I have this right but I would like someone to verify that.

```
function storageAmmount()
{
    system('stat /web/'.$user."/ | grep Size: > /web/".$user."/log/storage");
    $storage = fopen('/web/'.$user.'/log/storage');
    $storage = str_replace('Size:', " ", $storage);
    $storage = preg_replace('Blocks:(((A-Z), a-z), 1-9)','',$storage);
}
```

This is the line in the text file:

```
Size: 4096       Blocks: 8          IO            Block: 4096   directory
```

I am trying to get just the numeric value the proceeds "Size: ", the word Size: and everything else is usless to me.

I am mainly looking at the `preg_replace`. Is it just me or is regex a tad bit confusing? Any thoughts. Thanks for any help in advance.

Cheers!,

Phill

---

Ok,

Here is what the function looks like now:

```
function storageAmmount()
{
$storage = filesize('/web/'.$user.'/');
$final = $storage/(1024*1024*1024);
return $final;
}
```

Where would I put the number_format(), I am not really sure if it would go in the equation or in the return statement. I have tred it in both an all it returns is "0.00".

V1.

```
function storageAmmount()
{
$storage = filesize('/web/'.$user.'/');
$final = number_format($storage/(1024*1024*1024), 2);
return $final;
}
```

or V2.

```
function storageAmmount()
{
$storage = filesize('/web/'.$user.'/');
$final = $storage/(1024*1024*1024);
return number_format($final, 2);
}
```

neither work and they both return "0.00". Any thoughts?

Comment: You need to take a look at the [PCRE syntax reference](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php).

Comment: And the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Formatting code is just indentation by 4 spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to get the size of the file in bytes. If so why not just use the [filesize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php) function of PHP which takes the file name as its argument and returns the size of the file in bytes.

```
function storageAmmount(){    
    $storage = filesize('/web/'.$user);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I didn't think that existed. but another quick question....

Is this correct:

      $final = $storage/(1024*1024*1024);
  return number_format($final, 2);

Screenshow: http://grab.by/8eab

Answer (score 2):

No, you're not using `preg_replace` properly.

There's a *lot* of misunderstanding in your code; to correct it would mean I'd have to explain the basics of how Regex works. I really recommend reading a few primers on the subject. There's a good one here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

In fact, what you're trying to do here with the `str_replace` and the `preg_replace` together would be better achieved using a single `preg_match`.

Something like this would do the trick:

```
$matches = preg_match('/Size: (\d+)/',$storage);
$storage = $matches[1];
```

The `(\d+)` picks up any number of digits and puts them into an element in the $matches array. Putting `Size:` in front of that forces it to only recognise the digits that are immediately after Size: in your input string.

If your input string is consistently formatted in the way you described, you could also do it without using any `preg_` functions at all; just `explode()` on a space character and pick up the second element. No regex required.

Answer (score 2):

The best usage of regex is

```
// preg_match solution    
$storage = 'Size: 4096 Blocks: 8 IO Block: 4096 directory';
if (preg_match('/Size: (?P<size>\d+)/', $storage, $matches)) {
    return matches['size'];
}
```

But if you are doing it localy, you can use th php function `stat`

```
// php stat solution
$f = escapeshellcmd($user);
if ($stat = @stat('/web/'.$f.'/log/storage')) {
    return $stat['size'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bearing in mind the fact that you're already using string manipulation (don't quite get why - a single regular expression could handle it all), I don't know why you don't proceed down this path.

For example using explode:

```
function storageAmount($user) {
    system(escapeshellcmd('stat /web/'.$user.'/ | grep Size: > /web/'.$user.'/log/storage'));
    $storageChunks = explode(' ', file_get_contents('/web/'.$user.'/log/storage'));
    return $storageChunks[1];
}
```

Incidentally:

1. The $user variable doesn't exist within the scope of your function - you either need to pass it in as an argument as I've done, or make it a global.
2. You should really use [escapeshellcmd](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php) on all commands passed to system/exec, etc.
3. You're using fopen incorrectly. fopen returns a resource which you then need to read from via fread, etc. prior to using fclose. That said, I've replaced this with [file_get_contents](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) which does the open/read/close for you.
4. I'm not really sure what you're attempting to do with the system command, but I've left it as-is. However, you could just get the result of the grep back directly as the last string output rather than having to output it to a file. (This is what the [system](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) command returns.) You're also mixing ' and " as string delimiters - this won't work. (Just use one consistently.)
5. I suspect you actually want to the final line of "`df --si  /web/'.$user.'/'`" command as otherwise you'll always be returning the value 4096.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
$storage = preg_replace('Block:.*','',$storage)
```

?

Even better would be to use

```
 function storageAmmount()
 {
   exec('stat /web/'.$user.'/ | grep Size:',$output);
   preg_match("/Size: ([0-9]*).*/",$output[0],$matches);
   return $matches[1];
 }
```

(tested on my machine)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you also need delimiters, in this case I used `%`; `preg_match("%Size: ([0-9]*).*%", $storage, $matches)`